# How to prevent react datepicker from changing on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have this input div, which allows the user to enter an address and a date. When the user clicks the button, the address is transformed to coordinates(latitude and longitude).

The problem is, that whenever the 'Go!' button is clicked the date picker changes. Example: If you first enter 3/18/2021 as your date, when you click the button, the date is changed to 3/20/2021. I think it may have something to do with onChange/onClick.

However, I can't really get to the bottom of it. When I enter in the address field before the button is clicked, the date doesn't change, but when I have clicked the 'Go!' button and then try to edit the address the date changes on every keystroke.

Code:

```
function App() {
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('Oslo');
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [lat, setLat] = useState();
    const [long, setLong] = useState();

    const addressToLatitude = () => {
        const apiUrl =
            'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=' +
            address +
            '&key=a36f7bc238ea498bb701ac8e2f865655';
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((data) => {
                const lat = data.results[0].geometry.lat;
                const long = data.results[0].geometry.lng;
                setLat(lat);
                setLong(long);
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    };

    const [min, setMin] = useState('auto');
    const [max, setMax] = useState('auto');

    const clickHandler = (e) => {
        setMax(e.target.value);
        setMin(-e.target.value);
    };

    const clickHandlerAuto = (e) => {
        setMax(e.target.value);
        setMin(e.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div className='app'>
            <div className='card'>
                <div className='input-div'>
                    <input
                        className='input'
            type='text'
                        value={address}
            onChange={(e) => {
                            setAddress(e.target.value);
              console.log(e.target.value)
                        }}
                        placeholder='latitude'/>
            <DatePicker type='date' selected={date} onChange={(date) => setDate(date)}/>
                    <button
          type='submit'
                        onClick={() => {
                            addressToLatitude();
                        }}
                    >
                        Go!
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className='button-div'>
                    <button type='button' onClick={clickHandler} value='60'>
                        60
                    </button>
                    <button type='button' onClick={clickHandler} value='90'>
                        90
                    </button>
                    <button type='button' onClick={clickHandlerAuto} value='auto'>
                        AUTO
                    </button>
                </div> {lat && (
                    <div className='graph'>
                        <div className='altchar'>
                            <AltitudeChart
                                latitude={lat}
                                longitude={long}
                                date={date}
                                max={max}
                                min={min}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <AzimuthChart
                                latitude={lat}
                                longitude={long}
                                date={date}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: On a phone so can't test, but I wonder if you need to `preventDefault` on your button handler, and that not doing so is being treated as a form submission and causing your datepicker to revert to default of today's date.

Comment: @tmdesigned It doesnt't revert to the default day, it adds to days to the original date. So if i set the date to 4/20/2021 in the datepicker, as soon as i click the button, the date is 4/22/2021

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. The problem was, that in another file I did:

```
for(let i = 0; i <=24; i++){
      var altitude = SunCalc.getPosition(date.setHours(i, 0, 0), latitude, longitude).altitude * 180 / Math.PI
      let temp = new Data(i, altitude)
      data.push(temp.data().data)
    }
```

The .setHours(i, 0, 0) was the problem I don't really know why. But it was solved when I removed it :)